# assigning values to specific cells based on the values in a specific column

Tags: r

here is the that data that will help create the sample for the question asked below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5), Order_status_1 = c(1,1,0,0,1), Order_time_1 = c(20, 30, 0, 0, 47), 
Order_status_1 = c(0,1,1,1,1), Order_time_1 = c(0, 36, 12, 24, 88), Order_status_3 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 
0), Order_time_3 = c(0, 40, 25, 0, 0), Order_status_4 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Order_time_3 = c(0, 65, 0, 
0, 0),  Order_close_date = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)  )
```

## expected output

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5), Order_status_1 = c(1,1,0,0,1), Order_time_1 = c(20, 30, 0, 0, 47), 
Order_status_2 = c(0,1,1,1,1), Order_time_2 = c(100, 36, 12, 24, 88), Order_status_3 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 
0), Order_time_3 = c(100, 40, 25, 400, 500), Order_status_4 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Order_time_4 = 
c(100, 65, 300, 400, 500),  Order_close_date = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)  )
```

As you can see the value in the last (times) column is copied in the times column containing 0 -> after a non zero time value column.

I strongly feel the loop should start checking (0) starting from the last time column up till it reaches  a non zero value and then insert the value (100,200,300,400,500) in respective cells. The data contains multiple rows and this is just a sample from it. So kindly provide solution (example- for or if loops) which can runs the code for more than 1000 rows.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, we can use `apply` row-wise on `"time"` columns and replace the 0's after 1st occurrence of non-zero value with the last column value.

```
time_columns <- c(grep("time", names(df1)), ncol(df1))

df1[time_columns] <- t(apply(df1[time_columns], 1, function(x) 
            replace(x, x == 0 & seq_along(x) > which.max(x !=0), x[length(x)])))
```

Comment: It gives the folowing error:                                                                          Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, time_column, value = c(2, 4, 6, 8,  : 
  Supplied 325 items to be assigned to 13 items of column 'ID'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, time_column, value = c(2, 4, 6, 8,  :
  25 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector

Comment: @AashayMehta It looks like you have got a data.table whereas in the example you have data frame. Can you convert the data to dataframe and then try? `df1 <- data.frame(df1)`

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much @Ronak Shah

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table` to convert into long format, update appropriate rows, then pivot into a wide format as per desired output:

```
library(data.table)

#convert into long format
DT <- melt(setDT(df1), id.vars=c("ID", "Order_close_date"), 
    measure.vars=patterns("^Order_status", "^Order_time"),
    value.name=c("Order_status", "Order_time"),
    variable.name="Order", variable.factor=FALSE)

#update rows where Order_status is 0 and there is a 1 before then
DT[DT[, .I[Order_status==0 & cumsum(Order_status) > 0], ID]$V1, 
    Order_time := Order_close_date]

#pivot into wide format
ans <- dcast(DT, ID + Order_close_date ~ Order, value.var=c("Order_status","Order_time"))
setcolorder(ans, names(df1))[]
```

output:

```
  ID Order_status_1 Order_time_1 Order_status_2 Order_time_2 Order_status_3 Order_time_3 Order_status_4 Order_time_4 Order_close_date
1  1              1           20              0          100              0          100              0          100              100
2  2              1           30              1           36              1           40              1           65              200
3  3              0            0              1           12              1           25              0          300              300
4  4              0            0              1           24              0          400              0          400              400
5  5              1           47              1           88              0          500              0          500              500
```